# What's the equivalent of setConnectionTimeout() in latest Apache HTTP client?

Tags: java, apache, http

In one of the older versions of HTTP client I have used:

```
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpClient.getParams(), connectionTimeout);
```

Its now deprecated. What's the exact equivalent of setConnectionTimeout() in latest Apache HTTP client?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, when something is deprecated, the API docs will tell you what it's been deprecated in favor of. Looking at [the documentation for `HttpConnectionParams`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-4.3.x/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/params/HttpConnectionParams.html), we find:

> **Deprecated.**
>
> (4.3) use configuration classes provided 'org.apache.http.config' and 'org.apache.http.client.config'

So looking at [`org.apache.http.config`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-4.3.x/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/config/package-summary.html), we find [`RequestConfig.Builder`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/config/RequestConfig.Builder.html), which has [`setConnectTimeout`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/config/RequestConfig.Builder.html#setConnectTimeout(int)).